# REGEX_SUBSTR как выбрать текст между тегами с переводом строки?

Tags: sql, регулярные-выражения, oracle, plsql

Не могу победить.
Нужно вытащить все, что находится между тегами. Получается вытащить только то, что до перевода строки. Дальше не могу сообразить.

```
select regexp_substr('<message>aaa

bbb

ccc

</message>','<message>(.*)</message>',1,1, 'n') from DUAL
```

Comment: Может, `regexp_substr(col, '<message>(.*?)</message>', 1, 1, 'n', 1) from DUAL` поможет?

Comment: Тоже берет до перевода строки получем только : aaa

Comment: [Не может быть](http://rextester.com/WIBHQD36748)

Answer (score 3):

Используйте

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(col, '<message>(.*?)</message>', 1, 1, 'n', 1) from DUAL
```

Параметр `'n'` позволяет `.` находить символы перевода на новую строку. Последний параметр указывает `REGEXP_SUBSTR` вернуть только то значение, которые было захвачено первой захватывающей подмаской.

[**Онлайн-демо**](http://rextester.com/WIBHQD36748)

Answer (score 0):

Предлагаю парсить XML средствами для парсинга XML:

```
select extract(XMLTYPE('<message>aaa

bbb

ccc

</message>'), '/message/text()').getStringVal() str_from_xml from dual;
```

Результат:

```
STR_FROM_XML    
----------------
aaa

bbb

ccc
```

Answer (score -1):

**Как выяснилось, приведенный ниже способ для Oracle не работает. Но для тех, кто будет искать похожий ответ при работе с неоракловыми регулярками - может оказаться полезным.**

Попробуйте вместо .* применить [\s\S]*

Дело в том, что метасимвол . (точка) означает один любой (почти) символ, но в некоторых реализациях **исключая символ перевода строки**.

А символьный класс \s всегда включает символ перевода строки. Тогда выражение [\s\S]* будет соответствовать любому количеству любых символов, включая перевод строки.

Comment: Не стоит этого даже пробовать. В регулярных выражениях Oracle внутри квадратных скобок  escape-последовательности не поддерживаются, `[\s\S]` найдет ``\``, `S` и `s`. [См. демо](http://rextester.com/WETO84462).